# Trying to intersect POSIXct time intervals, but getting NA results

Tags: r, lubridate, posixct, intersect

I'm trying to find the duration of overlapping time. I know I am close with my code, but am getting NA results when I try to use the intersect function. I'm hoping someone can help me see where I am going wrong.

I have followed much of the example here [R Time periods overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606875/r-time-periods-overlapping) - but am not quite getting it correct. I think I must be missing a detail....

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
```

First I create 2 data tables with time periods to overlap

```
#create data table with observation shifts
start <- as.POSIXct(c("2017-08-01 04:52:00", "2017-08-01 05:56:00", "2017-08-01 13:25:00", "2017-08-01 13:50:00", "2017-08-01 14:29:00", "2017-08-01 15:28:00", "2017-08-01 15:57:00", "2017-08-01 17:22:00", "2017-08-01 17:37:00", "2017-08-01 19:10:00", "2017-08-01 22:52:00", "2017-08-02 04:00:00", "2017-08-02 05:02:00", "2017-08-02 08:47:00", "2017-08-02 13:31:00", "2017-08-02 18:13:00", "2017-08-03 04:31:00", "2017-08-03 05:34:00", "2017-08-03 07:20:00", "2017-08-03 08:25:00", "2017-08-03 09:33:00", "2017-08-03 12:20:00", "2017-08-03 14:04:00", "2017-08-03 21:21:00", "2017-08-07 18:22:00", "2017-08-08 10:20:00", "2017-08-08 14:05:00", "2017-08-08 15:57:00", "2017-08-08 17:01:00", "2017-08-09 04:27:00"),  format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "America/Halifax")
end <- as.POSIXct(c("2017-08-01 05:03:00", "2017-08-01 12:22:00", "2017-08-01 13:31:00", "2017-08-01 13:59:00",
"2017-08-01 15:23:00", "2017-08-01 15:56:00", "2017-08-01 17:21:00", "2017-08-01 17:35:00","2017-08-01 19:08:00", "2017-08-01 22:51:00", "2017-08-02 00:00:00", "2017-08-02 04:59:00", "2017-08-02 08:41:00","2017-08-02 13:27:00", "2017-08-02 17:45:00", "2017-08-03 00:02:00", "2017-08-03 05:32:00", "2017-08-03 07:18:00", "2017-08-03 08:24:00", "2017-08-03 09:27:00", "2017-08-03 11:59:00", "2017-08-03 13:54:00", "2017-08-03 16:20:00", "2017-08-04 00:01:00",
"2017-08-07 20:03:00", "2017-08-08 14:04:00", "2017-08-08 14:40:00", "2017-08-08 16:57:00", "2017-08-09 00:02:00", "2017-08-09 05:09:00"),  format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "America/Halifax")
effort <- data.table(start, end)

#create data table with daylight hours
day.start = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2017-07-31 05:30:00", 
                                  format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                                  tz = "America/Halifax"),
                       as.POSIXct("2017-08-23 05:30:00", 
                                  format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                                  tz = "America/Halifax"),by = "day")
day.end = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2017-07-31 20:00:00", 
                                format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                                tz = "America/Halifax"),
                     as.POSIXct("2017-08-23 20:00:00", 
                                format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                                tz = "America/Halifax"),by = "day")
daytimes = data.table(day.start, day.end)
```

Now to find where overlaps occur

```
#get ready to do foverlaps
setkey(effort, start, end)
setkey(daytimes, day.start, day.end)

#find overlapping periods
ov = foverlaps(daytimes,effort,type="any",nomatch=0)
# calculate intervals for effort daylight time periods that overlap
ov$int_eff = interval(ov$start, ov$end)
ov$int_day = interval(ov$day.start, ov$day.end)
# what time period is in common for each overlap?
```

Everything seems OK to this point. But when I try to find the intersection, I end up with a series of NA values

```
ov$int_o = intersect(ov$int_eff, ov$int_day)
# take a look to check
head(ov$int_o)
```

EDIT - including expected output here now.

After finding the intersects, I would then caulcate durations and then sum them up.  For this example, the total duration is 46 hours.

```
# now calculate durations of intersect intervals
ov$dur = as.duration(ov$int_o)
round(sum(ov$dur/dhours(1), na.rm=T), 1)
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the NA values, check to make sure you are using the most updated versions of each package used.

Comment: What exactly is the expected output? I might be overlooking something, but as far as I can tell there is no overlapping c.f. `all(daytimes$day.end[-nrow(daytimes)] < daytimes$day.start[-1])`

Comment: Thank you both for responding to my question. I'm not sure what the issue was as the first thing I did was to try quitting and re-starting R and then re-running my script. Weirdly it seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my missing expected output - I've edited the question to show the expected total.